# No Calls to throwing function occur

Tags: swift, try-catch

Hello I have I am trying to call a function from a third party library. which mean I will not have access to modify it. What I am trying to do is retrieve a variable which is converted to an array in the process. The issue is that one of this variables could be dictionary and the function will try to access it as an array and throw an error. the function it self is not declared as throws. is there any way to add a try catch block either way without receiving this warning?

Code:

```
let o = try? self.objectAsList(object) //function that could potential throw an error
if (o == nil) {
    print("There was an error")
}
return o
```

Comment: Just to confirm, the method `objectAsList` returns an array? or something else?

Comment: @murphguy thank you for your response, yes the method would return a list. For the function you can send in a json object, which converts it into a list. The function could potentially return an error if the object contains another Object in which one of the variables is a dictionary instead of type Any

Comment: So you want to be sure if the array contains Objects before or after it is created?

Comment: @murphguy not necessarily i want to make sure the function runs by checking with a try catch, then ill check if its nil or not.

Comment: Your usage of _throw an error_ or _return an error_ is so confusing. Non-`throws` method cannot be used with `try?` or `do`-`try`-`catch`. If you mean the method of the library may throw an `NSException`, then you cannot use `try?`. You may need to create an Objective-C wrapper to work with it. Please explain more precisely how the method is defined or imported and how it handles exceptions or errors.

Comment: @OOPer Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, the method that I am using does not gracefully handle exceptions or errors. I was trying to have my function do this on my end.

Comment: @paul590 If the library author didn't do his job properly, and subscripts arrays by out-of-range indices, force  casts, forcefully unwraps optionals, etc., then there is no way you can recover, without the library being modified. Unlike other languages like Java, C#, Python, etc., Swift does not do implicit checks for array bounds, nulls, etc. to throw errors. It just traps, to improve performance. The onus is on developers to not use force casting, force unwrapping, unsafebitcasts, unsafe array indexing, etc., unless they *really* know what they're doing.

Comment: @Alexander I come from a Java background and was hoping I could add a try catch block like I would there. The library that I am using is older and was written in Objective C. I wanted to verify if this was possible from my end, unfortunately, it sounds like it wont be.

Comment: @paul590 Yeah, it's quite different. Java essentially does an implicit `if (this == null) throw new NullPointerException();` at every method call, an array bounds check at every array access that throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, and a type check at every cast that throws a `ClassCastException`, etc. That's really costly, so Swift devs opted to not make such implicit checks everywhere